# Sticky sidebar, with a header that changes in height?

Tags: jquery, sidebar, sticky

I'm trying to achieve something and I cannot get it to work with existing jQuery plugins. What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

I have a sidebar, at about 200px from the top, when opening the website. Above that is my header, and below the header is a menu (that's sticky when it reaches the top of the menu).

Below this, I want the sidebar div (let's call it .sidebar) that also becomes sticky when it reaches the top (minus the menu, which should always stay on top of the page).

To make things a little bit clearer, this is a simple example of the HTML:

```
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="menu">always sticky through a jQuery sticky plugin</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">the part that SHOULD be sticky</div>
        <div class="content">the content that SHOULD scroll</div>
    </div>
```

Obviously, the .sidebar and .content are next to each other.

I think I'm forgetting a really simple solution, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've done what you're talking about before. Is this what you're looking to do?

http://dropthebit.com/demos/stickyfloat/stickyfloat.html

Looks like the code is now at:
https://gist.github.com/chaupt/728487

I had to modify this slightly, but the sidebar will remain fixed until you scroll and the top of the window touches the top of the element you want to scroll with the page.

Edit:

Ok, I think I see what you mean. Try this:

CSS:

```
    #header {background-color:#0000ff; color:#fff; height:50px; text-align:center; width:100%; z-index:10; }

    #wrapper {margin:0; padding:0; position:relative; z-index:1; }

    #menu {background-color:#000000; clear:both; color:#fff; height:25px; padding:5px; position:relative; width:100%; z-index:10; }

    #sidebar {background-color:#ff0000; color:#fff; float:left; margin:35px 0 0 0; position:relative; width:6em; }

    #content {background-color:#ff00ff; color:#fff; margin:0 0 0 6em; padding:35px 0 0 .5em; }

    p {margin:0 0 .5em  0; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">Menu</div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>Item1</li>
            <li>Item2</li>
            <li>Item3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then add the stickyFloat.js file from the gisthub location above, and add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#menu").stickyfloat({ duration: 400 });
        $("#sidebar").stickyfloat({ duration: 400 });
    });
</script>
```

I think this is what you're talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/qVwTY/2/

The top menu sticks to the top of the window, and the sidebar will stick to the bottom of that. I didn't test it in all the browsers I have, but it's working in the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not really, this sidebar sticks to the top of the page, while my sidebar needs to stick to the top of the MENU, which ALSO sticks to the top. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: So your top menu will always have a fixed position at the top of the window, and you want the side menu to stick to the bottom of this top menu when the window's scrolled and the two contact one another?
Hope this isn't starting to sound like some old-timey abbot/costello bit...

Comment: Because if that's the case, this plugin should be able to accomplish this; you'll probably just have to add in a top margin to the sticky-start position. I don't think it'll be too terribly difficult. 
I'll take a crack later today if this is indeed what you're having problems with and nobody else has helped you out.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what I'm trying to achieve. For some reason I have not been able to make this work, I believe I have used the same code you gave me before as well.